# Why did circuit breaker trigger when I connected multimeter to red and black wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Today, I was trying to measure the voltage between red and black wires connected to our thermostat (just out of curiosity).  I touched the COM lead to the black wire and the red lead to the red wire.  There was a spark and the circuit breaker kicked in.

I was wondering why this happened.  Currently, as I understand it, red and black are both "hot" wires with and the multimeter can be modeled as a very large resistor.  I don't know how the full circuit is created but I can't think of any configuration that could have created a short.  So I'm chalking it to either misunderstanding circuits/multimeter, not understanding how the house is wired or both.

Two other things I should note that seem relevant:

- There was a ground (unsheathed) cable nearby and it's hard to tell if I touched that by mistake while also touching one of the wires.  That could definitely have caused a short as I currently understand it.
- I also was having trouble getting the leads to touch so maybe I just created an arc?

Comment: What range/function was your multimeter set to, and which jacks on the meter did you have the meter's leads plugged into?

Comment: This sounds like a line voltage thermostat - e.g., a simple thermostat on an electric resistance heater, as opposed to a typical low voltage thermostat controlling furnace/air handler/air conditioner/heat pump/etc. But please confirm.

Comment: > ThreePhaseEel

Multimeter was set to V~.

The black lead was in COM and the red lead was in V setting (I have the [Amprobe AM-510](https://www.amprobe.com/product/am-510/) so the right 2 ports and the first dial setting clockwise of OFF).  Using the same settings but touching COM to ground and V to one of the hot wires gave 120V without triggering the breaker.

Comment: > manassehkatz

Yes, I believe this is a double pole line voltage thermostat (4 connection points: 2 red, 2 black).  When I measured the voltage connected to ground and hot, it was 120VAC.

Comment: @lycus AFAIK you got everything setup correctly. Can you take a picture and also see if your stuff are still working? Black marks can indicate what you shorted and it is possible you touched a ground.

Comment: My money is on your last paragraph, you touched something you didn't mean to touch.  Keep in mind with a GFCI/RCD or AFCI breaker, those can trip *before* you get any blinding flashes of light.

Comment: > Nelson There was a black mark on the hot wire but I didn't think of checking the ground (need to re-open the thermostat to check).  I am planning on re-opening the thermostat but want to make sure I get some insulating tape before I do it (a lot of exposed wire very close to each other which others believe may have lead to the short in the first place).  So hopefully I will get a definitive answer to this soon!

Comment: A meter set to ohms or amps will be a short to line voltage , the meter has to be on the correct function and the leads plugged into the correct ports. Higher end meters have protective fuses inside but the breaker will still trip as it may sees the meter as a short circuit. I have had several meters trip breakers when apprentices forgot to change a setting.

Comment: > Nelson, Opened up the thermostat again and it took some digging but there was a black mark on the ground as well.  So it looks like I caused a short by connecting ground to hot.